# Android Studio: Using Common Java Classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

This is insane to me, I've been searching all night, but can't figure out how to do this.

I have the following directory structure:

```
|
|Android Project1
|  (app, build, lib, etc)
|
|Android Project2
|  (app, build, lib, etc)
|
|Common Classes
|  (Constants.java, Config.java)
```

In Android Project1 and Android Project2, I would like to use the Constant.java class that has definitions for a lot of things that both Android Project1 and Android Project2 have.

How, do I use those java classes in either of those Android Projects?  It's like if stuff isn't inside of the Android Project itself, it's a huge pain in the ass to get Android Studio to see/use/import/whatever I need.  I've been Googling for hours, and haven't found a perfect, elegant solution.

In my specific implementation, the common classes contain a TCP client library, and custom class for my project; both pure Java.  I have a tiny test application, and a very large production application, both of which use the common classes.  I want to keep the pure Java common stuff separate from each project's Android stuff.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to tell AS how to get them. Something like library would work but, i don't think local access will work (at least thats what I get you're trying to do).

Comment: "Something like library would work". I don't know what that means.

Comment: Ah..I meant making the 'Common Classes' a library project.

Comment: I'm open to that solution as well. I've seen some people say to create a new module (Java Library). But if I do that from within AS, it, again, puts it /inside/ a project rather than outside of it.

Comment: Well, since you are aware of library projects I won't post that as an answer. Yeah, to use that project, the AS will need to put it inside itself somehow. However, libraries are much sleeker way to include project dependency.

Comment: I know how to create it, but I don't know how to reference it from the second project.  Since it's out of the second project, and inside the 1st project. Hopefully that makes sense.

If I can /import/ the module from inside a totally different project, I would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put Common Classes as a library project. To make a new libraray project, in AS: Choose File > New > New Module and select Android Library. To change an existing application to library change in your build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.applicaion'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

To use this library in another project you can:

```
1 - Click File > New Module.
2 - Click Import .JAR/.AAR Package then click Next.
3 - Enter the location of the AAR or JAR file then click Finish.
```

Or, Import the library module to your project:

```
Click File > New > Import Module.
Enter the location of the library module directory then click Finish.
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Okay, so what it sounds like is that if I want to keep the Java stuff completely out of the Android projects, I need to make a new 3rd project, then select "New Module" from inside that project.  So I have 3 AS projects, two of which are my actual apps, and the third that contains the Java library. Does that sound right?

Comment: You create the third project using 'New Module'. But yeah, you'd finally end up with 3 projects: 2 app projects and 1 library project which will build .aar file which you will ise in first two using the method described above.